# References/Links to reset sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, appendices

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{test}
\clearpage

\section{test}
\clearpage

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{test}
\clearpage

\section{test}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Please notice that when in TOC one clicks on the A chapter, the link takes it to the 1st chapter, same for B->2 and would be so on. How to tell the hyperlinks to go to the reset chapter instead of the first one in the document?
I would appreciate all help.

Edit: appendix doesnt seem to be shown in TOC:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{test}
\clearpage

\section{test}
\clearpage

\appendix{test}
\clearpage

\appendix{test}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\appendix` lalala

Comment: But `\appendix` is not shown in table of contents

Comment: It is not shown in your example either?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: `\appendix{test}` is **really** wrong ;-)

Comment: Well, maybe you should get the reference manual and read what `\appendix`  does? `\appendix \section{Wombat}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the OP example fails is the reset of the section counter without taking into account that `\theHsection` should be changed too -- doing so will lead to correct hyper anchors.

The `appendix` package takes care of this and `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` should be used in order to get everything setup, as well as the `toc` option, if needed (omitted here)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A nice title}
\clearpage

\section{Another nice title}
\clearpage


\begin{appendices}

\section{A very nice title}
\clearpage

\section{A sophisticated title}
\clearpage
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I need. The only problem is that now in the TOC a link called Appendices appears- is there a way to remove it?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: You don't want the link or no `Appendices` in ToC at all?

Comment: I dont want the word apendices in toc

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Just remove the `toc` option from the `\usepackage[toc]{appendix}` then -- it's described in the manual ;-)